# "TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects" when pickling a deep learning model

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, classification, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

When I run

```
pickle.dump(model,open('modelDL.pkl','wb'))
```

I get

```
TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects
```

I have a created a deep learning model which I am trying to save. The model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add( Dense(30,activation='relu') )
model.add( Dropout(0.5) ) 
model.add( Dense(20,activation='relu') )
model.add( Dropout(0.5) ) 
model.add( Dense(20,activation='relu') )
model.add( Dropout(0.5) )     
model.add( Dense(1,activation='sigmoid') )

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use tensorflow's built in model saving functionality? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save

Comment: Thank you Bhaskar!
I am able to save and load the model using tensorflow.
But I am not sure why I was unable to do it using the pickle, because I used to save machine learning models using the pickle.dump method.
If you could answer what is the error means , that would be great.

Comment: Maybe this solution could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42763323/8196143

Comment: Currently tensorflow supports the model can be saved in two different file formats (`SavedModel` and `HDF5`). The TensorFlow `SavedModel` format is the default file format in `TF2.x`. However, models can be saved in `HDF5` format. In `TF1.x` it defaults to  `HDF5`.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

can't pickle weakref comes because Deep Learning models are too large and pickle only used for storing small models

Use this : HDF5 used for storing large data

```py
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
```

returns a compiled model

identical to the previous one

```py
model1 = load_model('my_model.h5')

y_pred = model1.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Worked for me !  Kudos for the post-- put an end to my 3-day search !!!