# Python 2.7: Appending Data to Table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I am reading data from image files and I want to append this data into a single HDF file. Here is my code:

```
datafile = pd.HDFStore(os.path.join(path,'imageData.h5'))
for file in fileList: 
     data = {'X Position' :  pd.Series(xpos, index=index1),
             'Y Position' :  pd.Series(ypos, index=index1),
             'Major Axis Length' :  pd.Series(major, index=index1),
             'Minor Axis Length' :  pd.Series(minor, index=index1), 
             'X Velocity' :  pd.Series(xVelocity, index=index1),
             'Y Velocity' :  pd.Series(yVelocity, index=index1) }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    datafile['df'] = df
    datafile.close()
```

This is obviously incorrect as it overwrites each set of data with the new one each time the loop runs.

If instead of `datafile['df'] = df`, I use

```
datafile.append('df',df)
```

OR

```
df.to_hdf(os.path.join(path,'imageData.h5'), 'df', append=True, format = 'table')
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Can only append to Tables
```

I have referred to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#table-format) and other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637271/iteratively-writing-to-hdf5-stores-in-pandas), without avail.

So, I am hoping someone can explain why this isn't working and how I can successfully append all the data to one file. I am willing to use a different method (perhaps pyTables) if necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The second way (`df.to_hdf(..., format="table", append=True)`) is actually the right one. Have you tried using that (without all of the `HDFStore` stuff) with a fresh file?

Comment: @filmor You mean remove the line where I create the empty HDF file? Tried that, same error. Maybe the problem is that the data is in a DataFrame and not a table?

Comment: No, the error message is referring to the internal HDF5 table format that is used. IIRC in older versions of pandas (btw, which one are you using?) `HDFStore` used the `fixed` format by default which doesn't allow appending. The `table` format is the one used by PyTables.

Comment: Version 0.11.0 - I tried it on a fresh file and it worked, but without the for loop.

Comment: @filmor So according to what you said, I should I use PyTables instead? Or should the `to_hdf` function allow appending?

Comment: If you use `format="table"` `to_hdf` should allow appending by using PyTables internally, no need to do that yourself. You might want to update pandas, though. What does "and it worked" mean? Would you update the question?

Comment: in 0.11 to_hdf didn't pass thru keywords so that will not work. best to upgrade - current version is 0.13.1

Comment: @Jeff I upgraded to 0.13.0. The `to_hdf` method also works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in 0.11. Once you create a group (e.g the label where you are storing data, the 'df' here). If you store a `fixed` format it will overwrite (and if you try to append will give you the above error msg); if you write a `table` format you *can* append. Note that in 0.11, `to_hdf` does not correctly pass keywords thru to the underlying function so you can use it ONLY to write a `fixed` format.

```
datafile = pd.HDFStore(os.path.join(path,'imageData.h5'),mode='w')
for file in fileList: 
     data = {'X Position' :  pd.Series(xpos, index=index1),
             'Y Position' :  pd.Series(ypos, index=index1),
             'Major Axis Length' :  pd.Series(major, index=index1),
             'Minor Axis Length' :  pd.Series(minor, index=index1), 
             'X Velocity' :  pd.Series(xVelocity, index=index1),
             'Y Velocity' :  pd.Series(yVelocity, index=index1) }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    datafile.append('df',df)
datafile.close
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. The only change I had to make was to add `datafile.open()` before appending.

Comment: For clarity, the only difference here is the addition of `mode='w'` in the first line. In that case, what is the default mode?

Comment: default mode is to append (to the file); w creates a new file