# Python pandas append dataframe with array content to hdf file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf, hdfstore

How can I append a dataframe to another dataframe which is already saved in a file without loading it from the file? (Python 3.6 & Pandas 1.0.1)
Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[['A01','A02'],'B0','C0'],[['A11','A12'],'B1','C1'],[['A21','A22'],'B2','C2']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C'])

data2 = [[['A31','A32'],'B3','C3'],[['A41','A42'],'B4','C4'],[['A51','A52'],'B5','C5']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['A','B','C'])

print(df.append(df2,ignore_index=True))

#version 1:
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5','a')
store.append(key='foo',value=df)#, format='t', data_columns=True)
store.append(key='foo',value=df2)#, format='t', data_columns=True, append=True)

#version 2
df.to_hdf(path_or_buf='test.h5',key='foo',mode='w',format='t')
df2.to_hdf(path_or_buf='test.h5',key='foo',mode='a',append=True,format='t',data_columns=True)

#version 3
df.to_hdf(path_or_buf='test.h5',key='foo',mode='w',format='f')
df2.to_hdf(path_or_buf='test.h5',key='foo',mode='a',append=True,format='f',data_columns=True)

df3 = pd.read_hdf('test.h5',key='foo',mode='r')
print(df3)
```

version 1: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
version 2: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
version 3: ValueError: Can only append to Tables

This question was asked similarly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035360/python-2-7-appending-data-to-table-in-pandas) but quite a while ago. I tried it with an older pandas version but this causes even more problems.

**EDIT:**
It seems that the issue are the arrays as content. If I use only the Bs and Cs, like so, it works:

```
data = [['B0','C0'],['B1','C1'],['B2','C2']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['B','C'])
data2 = [['B3','C3'],['B4','C4'],['B5','C5']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['B','C'])
```

Does anybody know a possibility how I can get it to work despite using arrays as content?

Comment: _This question was asked similarly here but quite a while ago. I tried it with an older pandas version but this causes even more problems._ Did you try the solution, or something similar, with a recent Pandas version?

Comment: @AMC yes I did but there are more issues with incompatible python versions and so on. I use pandas 1.0.1 and in the other question they used pandas 0.11.

Comment: What do you mean? I was just asking if you tried the solution with a recent Pandas version, and if it doesn't work straight away, see if the general method can be kept and tweak the code to modernize it.

Comment: Yes I did try the solution with a recent pandas version and it does not work.
I tried it with the outdated version of pandas and this causes more problems with the python version I use and other libraries.
And yes I tried to tweek the old solution to find a better one but non of them worked.